# How to Export multiple selected features to PDFs with Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, pdf

I have 77 polygons that mark areas of a satellite image that I want to export as separate PDFs. Each of the PDFs should contain just the polygon (and as much as the surroundings to fill out the data frame, and should be zoomed so that they fill out each A4 page (i.e. the scale are allowed to vary).

It is easy to obtain a list of the polygons, but how is the rest accomplished with Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly (without Python) using the [data driven pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003n000000). If you need more control, you can use arcpy.mapping in Python. There are several example on this site. see [Do Data Driven Pages enable PDF merging without losing layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20456/data-driven-pages-mapbook) or [Automating plan report generation using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81986/need-help-to-automatize-report-generation) for examples (you can use the tag data driven pages)

Comment: Perfect. Very easy to set up. I had not realised that data driven pages could be used for that.

Comment: @JonPedersen If that answered your Question be sure to reward the answerer by clicking the Accept (big green tick) button.